# ¿Como generar un archivo con datos del sistema y descargarlo con Node JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, archivo

El sistema tiene una formulario, del lado del backend recupero esos datos, lo que no puedo es esos datos descargarlos en un archivo .txt.

Estaba usando `fs.writefile()`, pero cuando el sistema esta subido en la nube no accede a la carpeta destino.

```
exports.create_ingreso = function (req, res) {
   var new_ingreso = new Ingreso(req.body);
   //quiero descargar los datos de req.body  en un archivo.txt
   fs.writeFile(
      'nameFile.txt',
      new_ingreso.nameUser,
      error => {
        if (error)
          console.log(error, 'el archivo no fue creado');
        else
          console.log('El archivo fue creado');
        });
  }
```

El archivo se crea sin problemas lo que quiero es saber si existe alguna forma de que se pueda descargar este archivo o si existen otra forma de descargar.

Esta viendo una forma pero no estoy seguro de como continuar.

`var file = fs.writeFile(....);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un ejemplo básico que genera un archivo **txt** llamado **ejemplo.txt** y dentro tendría el texto **Hola, mundo** sería este:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ejemplo.txt");
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
  res.charset = "UTF-8";
  res.write("Hola, mundo");
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Example app listening on port 8080!");
});
```

Basado en tu ejemplo debería servirte algo como esto:

```
exports.create_ingreso = function(req, res) {
  var new_ingreso = new Ingreso(req.body);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=ejemplo.txt');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.charset = 'UTF-8';
  res.write(new_ingreso.nameUser);
  res.end();
};
```

También existen otras formas de hacerlo como por ejemplo generar el archivo txt en la carpeta publica del server de esa forma se puede descargar el archivo accediendo a la url publica del mismo.

Comment: Genial, esto resulto.